# Android ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, android, multithreading

**ScheduledExecutorService**

Is **ScheduledExecutorService** run on main thread or on background thread i go throught the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)  but didt found.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Android, but usually, if there is a thread called "main", then it will be running application specific code, not library code.  Why mention it?  Because it is _never_ possible for a method call to run [some piece of code] on thread `t` if thread `t` is doing something else.  In fact, really, the very idea of code running on a thread is Bass Ackward.  Code doesn't run on threads.  Code doesn't run at all.  Code just sits there.  It's the _threads_ that run the code.  You'll go farther if you think of threads as independent agents that run around, following your instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScheduledExecutorService` uses background threads, from a thread pool specified implicitly or explicitly when you create an instance from [the `Executors` set of factory methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Note that `ScheduledExecutorService` is a standard Java class (`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`). The main application thread is something from the Android framework.